Formula for the Nth bit_count (or population count) of size M
I am interested in finding a simple formula for determining the nth time a particular bit_count occurs in the sequence of natural numbers. Specifically, what is the relationship between K and N in the table below. So, for example, what is the N of the K=123456789123456789123456789, I can tell you the M is 50, but what is the N?
length = 5
for K in range(2**length):
    bits = bin(K)[2:].zfill(length)
    M    = K.bit_count() # numbers of "1"s in the binary sequence
    N    = sum(1 for i in range(K) if M==i.bit_count())
    print(f'{K: <2}',bits,M,N)

'''
K  bits  M N
0  00000 0 0
1  00001 1 0
2  00010 1 1
3  00011 2 0
4  00100 1 2
5  00101 2 1
6  00110 2 2
7  00111 3 0
8  01000 1 3
9  01001 2 3
10 01010 2 4
11 01011 3 1
12 01100 2 5
13 01101 3 2
14 01110 3 3
15 01111 4 0
16 10000 1 4
17 10001 2 6
18 10010 2 7
19 10011 3 4
20 10100 2 8
21 10101 3 5
22 10110 3 6
23 10111 4 1
24 11000 2 9
25 11001 3 7
26 11010 3 8
27 11011 4 2
28 11100 3 9
29 11101 4 3
30 11110 4 4
31 11111 5 0
...
'''


So, I appear to have solved half of it. It appears that
N = (K-sum(2**i for i in range(M)).bit_count()

whenever N<=M. This appears to be because,
K = sum(2**i for i in range(M)) + sum(2**(M-1-i) for i in range(N))

again, whenever N<=M. It appears that N<=M occurs about half the time.
length = 5
for K in range(2**length):
    bits = bin(K)[2:].zfill(length)
    M    = K.bit_count() # numbers of "1"s in the binary sequence
    N    = sum(1 for i in range(K) if M==i.bit_count())
    if N <= M:
        A = sum(2**i for i in range(M)) + sum(2**(M-1-i) for i in range(N))
        B = (K - sum(2**i for i in range(M))).bit_count()
    else:
        A = '-'
        B = '-'
    print(f'{K: <2}',bits,M,N,A,B)


This sounds more like a [math.se] question, not a programming question.

If I say "pop_count" over on math.stackexchange they will immediately remove the question. I tried to use the "%" sign for a mod symbol a few weeks ago and was immediately rejected.

Try using the terminology of number theory, not computer programming. You don't use computer programming to develop a formula, you use computer programming to implement the formula once you've determined it mathematically.

Since, for any K, N is the sum of all integers < K that share the bit-count M with K, you can either iterate through the series (which is a straightforward, if very computationally intensive programming problem), or come up with some pattern in that series (which seems like a non-trivial math problem). On the brute force programming path, you could instead generate all numbers < K with a specific bit-count instead and sum those.

@Grismar Ya, it definitely feels non-trivial. It just seems like this is something someone may have seen before. I tried graphing out the (M,N) pairs on a coordinate system and it seems like there is a pattern, but again non-trivial. pop_count is such a common function in computer programming and signal processing, I am hoping someone knows more than me.

By the way, I said 'sum' for some reason, but of course it's the count.

@barmar I don't wholly disagree with you that this is more of a Mathematics question, but I also feel it's really just asking for an algorithmic approach to the mathematics question. It's fair to call it a Computer Science question, and had it been phrased in terms of "what is a more efficient way to solve this problem" with a given solution, it would be more of a Programming question. But you're right that it's rather fringe. I disagree with the notion that stuff like this is 'math up front' though - many math problems get solved by algorithmic play. Phrased properly, it's suitable for SO.

@EricPostpischil you should post that as an answer

Your N value starts at 0. Surely it should start at 1?

@Nick: Okay, done.

I don't know Python so this is Ruby. The algorithm should be easy to translate. The idea is, for each set bit (going from smaller to larger), count all numbers which are the same to the left of that bit, have the same number of set bits at that bit and to its right, but don't have that bit set.

Traverse your input's bits from smallest to largest.
Keep track of the set bits seen and the total bits seen.
Count all numbers with the same number of set bits seen but a smaller max set bit (than the current index) each time you encounter a set bit.
E.g., when reaching the smaller 1 in 10100, we add 2 to the count because there are 2 numbers with 1 set bit and a smaller max set bit: 10 and 01.

Code:
def g(k)
  set_bits_seen = 0
  all_bits_seen = 0
  
  total = 0
  
  while k > 0
    all_bits_seen += 1
    
    if k % 2 == 1 # cur bit is set
      set_bits_seen += 1
      if all_bits_seen > set_bits_seen
        total += n_choose_k(all_bits_seen - 1, set_bits_seen)
      end
    end
    k /= 2
  end
  return total
end

def n_choose_k(n, k)
  return 1 if k == 0 or k == n
  (k + 1 .. n).reduce(:*) / (1 .. n - k).reduce(:*)
end

Results:
1.upto(20) do |i|
  puts "#{i.to_s(2)}  --  #{g(i)}"
end

1  --  0
10  --  1
11  --  0
100  --  2
101  --  1
110  --  2
111  --  0
1000  --  3
1001  --  3
1010  --  4
1011  --  1
1100  --  5
1101  --  2
1110  --  3
1111  --  0
10000  --  4
10001  --  6
10010  --  7
10011  --  4
10100  --  8

And for your large example:
> g(123456789123456789123456789)
=> 3594960708495168399327022


This does indeed do the thing I think it should be doing. How about backwards? If I gave you (N,M)=(50,3594960708495168399327022), how do you find K?

@BobbyOcean I think there's a simple approach but I don't have time to confirm in now or write it up; probably tomorrow. Would you consider posting it as a separate, related question? Someone else may beat me to the punch, which is fine.

I think I might see how to do it backwards. Thanks very much, I knew it had to be something like a sum of binomial coefficients at each of the set bits.

Result
Only a few arithmetic operations per bit position are needed to calculate in either direction (from the bit string k to the number of bits m and the index n or from the number of bits and the index to the bit string). Python and C implementations are given below.
To illustrate the algorithms are composed of a few elementary arithmetic operations per bit position, the C version is shown here without comments. Fully commented code is below:
static void BitStringToIndex(unsigned Bits, unsigned *NBits, unsigned *Index)
{
    unsigned b = 0;
    while (Bits>>b & 1)
        ++b;
    unsigned m = b, n = 0, c = 1;
    while (Bits>>++b)
        if (Bits>>b & 1)
            n += (c = c * b / ++m);
        else
            c = c * b / (b-m);
    *NBits = m;
    *Index = n;
}


static unsigned IndexToBitString(unsigned m, unsigned n)
{
    unsigned b = m, c = 1;
    for (unsigned t; (t = c * (b+1) / ((b+1)-m)) <= n; ++b)
        c = t;
    unsigned k = 0;
    for (; n; --b)
    {
        if (c <= n)
        {
            n -= c;
            k |= 1;
            c = c * m-- / b;
        }
        else
            c = c * (b-m) / b;
        k <<= 1;
    }
    k <<= b;
    k |= (1u << m) - 1;
    return k;
}

Algorithms
The number of ways to arrange m 1 bits in b positions, with 0 bits in the other m−b positions, is bCm = b! / m! / (b−m)!.1
This answer numbers the bit positions 0 for the least significant, then 1 for the next, and so on. The binary numeral 10000 has a 1 in bit position 4 and has 4 zeros to the “right” of it or “below” it.
Consider a list in ascending order of the binary numerals with a fixed number of 1 bits. Before the bit in position b can become 1 (if it does not start as 1), either from the start of the list or from the last time it changed from 1 to 0, the b bits to its right must go through all bCm arrangements of m 1 bits in b bits, where m is the number of 1 bits in position b and below. A numeral with 1 bits in positions b0, b1, b2,…, each with corresponding m0, m1, m2,… , appears after b0Cm0 steps in the list to get 1 in bit b0 plus b1Cm1 steps in the list to get 1 in bit b1, and so on. So all we have to do to find the position of this numeral in the list is add bCm for each 1 bit other than those together at the right.2 The routine BitStringToIndex below shows that.
Conversely, given a number of bits m and an index n, we find the greatest b before bCm exceeds n, and that tells us where the leading 1 bit in the bit string is. The string we seek is then n − bCm steps in the list beyond where this leading 1 bit first appears, so we can update n and then identify the position of the next 1 bit. The routine IndexToBitString shows this.
This description of the algorithms mentions bCm repeatedly. However, we need not calculate it from scratch each time. As we progress from bCm to either b+1Cm or b+1Cm+1, the value of C changes by a single factor in the numerator and a single factor in the denominator. This is shown in comments in the code below. Thus one multiplication and one division per bit position suffice to maintain an ongoing value for this function.
Python Implementation
# At several points, comments mention maintaining c = C(b, m).  This means
# that, as the values of b and/or m change, the value of c is modified so
# that it remains equal to C(b, m) for the new values of b or m.


# Convert bit string Bits (a binary numeral) to the number of 1 bits it
# contains and the index of that string in ascending lexicographic order of the
# strings with that number of 1 bits.
def BitStringToIndex(Bits):

    # Set b to the position number of the lowest 0 bit in Bits.
    b = 0
    while Bits>>b & 1:
        b += 1

    # Start with number of bits b and index 0.  Maintain c = C(b, m) =
    # b! / m! / (b-m)!, the number of ways to arrange m 1 bits and b-m 0 bits
    # in b positions.
    m = b
    n = 0
    c = 1

    # Increment b and continue while there are further 1 bits at or above b.
    b += 1
    while Bits>>b:

        # If bit b is 1, count another 1 bit (++m) and add to the index n
        # the number of arrangements we have passed -- all the arrangements
        # of m 1 bits in the b positions below position b, C(b, m).
        #
        # Update c to transition to the new C(b, m) from the prior
        # C(b-1, m-1): C(b, m) / C(b-1, m-1) =
        # b! / m! / (b-m)! / ((b-1)! / (m-1)! / ((b-1) - (m-1))!) = b / m.
        if Bits>>b & 1:
            m += 1
            c = c * b // m
            n += c

        # If bit is 0, do not update the index.  Merely update c:
        # C(b, m) / C(b-1, m) =
        # b! / m! / (b-m)! / ((b-1)! / m! / ((b-1)-m)!) = b / (b-m).
        else:
            c = c * b // (b-m)

        b += 1

    # Return the bit count and the index.
    return [m, n]


# Convert a number of 1 bits, m, and an index, n, of a bit string in ascending
# lexicographic order of the strings with that number of 1 bits to the bit
# string (a binary numeral).
def IndexToBitString(m, n):

    # Find highest bit and maintain c = C(b, m) = b! / m! / (b-m)!,
    # the number of ways to arrange m 1 bits and b-m 0 bits in b positions.
    b = m
    c = 1
    while 1:
        t = c * (b+1) // ((b+1)-m)
        if n < t:
            break
        c = t
        b += 1

    # Start the index k at zero.  For each bit position b, in descending
    # order, test whether the index n indicates we have passed C(b, m) prior
    # arrangements.  If so, there is a 1 at the current bit position, and we
    # decrement m by 1 to account for the 1 bit here and n by C(b, m) to
    # account for the number of prior arrangements.
    k = 0

    # Continue until base case, index n is zero, at which time there are m 1
    # bits in the m low positions.
    while 0 < n:
    
        # If n equals or exceeds C(b, m), we passed all prior arrangements
        # of m bits in the b lower positions, so there must be a 1 bit here.
        if c <= n:
            # Decrement n for the number of prior arrangements.
            # 
            # Put a 1 bit at this position.  (We shift k later.)
            # 
            # Update c to C(b-1, m-1) from C(b, m):  C(b-1, m-1) / C(b, m) =
            # (b-1)! / (m-1)! / ((b-1)-(m-1))! / (b! / m! / (b-m)!) =
            # m / b.
            # 
            # Decrement m by 1 for this 1 bit.
            n -= c
            k |= 1
            c = c * m // b
            m -= 1

        # Otherwise, merely update c to C(b-1, m) from C(b, m):
        # C(b-1, m) / C(b, m) =
        # (b-1)! / m! / ((b-1)-m)! / (b! / m! / (b-m)!) = (b-m) / b.
        else:
            c = c * (b-m) // b

        # Shift k to work on next bit position.
        k <<= 1;

        b -= 1

    # The loop above can be made sufficient to construct all of k by running
    # it down to a final iteration in which b is zero (which requires some
    # care in the loop limit and avoiding division by zero in updating c).
    # That is mathematically aesthetic, but, once n reaches zero, we can
    # handle the final bits directly with the code below.

    # The bit at position 0 in the value under construction in k is destined
    # to be bit b in the final value, so shift k.
    k <<= b

    # Here n is zero which is the index for all m 1 bits in the low
    # positions. Add this to k, and we are done.
    k |= (1 << m) - 1

    return k;


for k in range (32):
    m, n = BitStringToIndex(k)
    print(k, m, n)
    t = IndexToBitString(m, n)
    if t != k:
        print("Error, expected ({}, {}) -> {} but got {}.".format(m, n, t, k))
        exit(1)

C Implementation
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*  At several points, comments mention maintaining c = C(b, m).  This means
    that, as the values of b and/or m change, the value of c is modified so
    that it remains equal to C(b, m) for the new values of b or m.
*/


/*  Convert bit string Bits (a binary numeral) to the number of 1 bits it
    contains, *NBits, and the index, *Index, of that string in ascending
    lexicographic order of the strings with that number of 1 bits.
*/
static void BitStringToIndex(unsigned Bits, unsigned *NBits, unsigned *Index)
{
    //  Set b to the position number of the lowest 0 bit in Bits.
    unsigned b = 0;
    while (Bits>>b & 1)
        ++b;

    /*  Start with number of bits b and index 0.  Maintain c = C(b, m) =
        b! / m! / (b-m)!, the number of ways to arrange m 1 bits and b-m 0 bits
        in b positions.
    */
    unsigned m = b, n = 0, c = 1;

    //  Increment b and continue while there are further 1 bits at or above b.
    while (Bits>>++b)

        /*  If bit b is 1, count another 1 bit (++m) and add to the index n
            the number of arrangements we have passed -- all the arrangements
            of m 1 bits in the b positions below position b, C(b, m).

            Update c to transition to the new C(b, m) from the prior
            C(b-1, m-1): C(b, m) / C(b-1, m-1) =
            b! / m! / (b-m)! / ((b-1)! / (m-1)! / ((b-1) - (m-1))!) = b / m.
        */
        if (Bits>>b & 1)
            n += (c = c * b / ++m);

        /*  If bit is 0, do not update the index.  Merely update c:
            C(b, m) / C(b-1, m) =
            b! / m! / (b-m)! / ((b-1)! / m! / ((b-1)-m)!) = b / (b-m).
        */
        else
            c = c * b / (b-m);

    //  Return the bit count and the index.
    *NBits = m;
    *Index = n;
}


/*  Convert a number of 1 bits, m, and an index, n, of a bit string in
    ascending lexicographic order of the strings with that number of 1 bits to
    the bit string (a binary numeral).
*/
static unsigned IndexToBitString(unsigned m, unsigned n)
{
    /*  Find highest bit and maintain c = C(b, m) = b! / m! / (b-m)!,
        the number of ways to arrange m 1 bits and b-m 0 bits in b positions.

        The unusual loop construction is due to the fact we want to test
        whether increasing b would yield n < C(b, m), in which case we want to
        use b before increasing it.  So a temporary value t is assigned the
        value of what C(b, m) would be if b were increased.  If it does not
        exceed n, c is updated and b is increased, and the loop continues.
    */
    unsigned b = m, c = 1;
    for (unsigned t; (t = c * (b+1) / ((b+1)-m)) <= n; ++b)
        c = t;

    /*  Start the index k at zero.  For each bit position b, in descending
        order, test whether the index n indicates we have passed C(b, m) prior
        arrangements.  If so, there is a 1 at the current bit position, and we
        decrement m by 1 to account for the 1 bit here and n by C(b, m) to
        account for the number of prior arrangements.
    */
    unsigned k = 0;

    /*  Continue until base case, index n is zero, at which time there are m 1
        bits in the m low positions.
    */
    for (; n; --b)
    {
        /*  If n equals or exceeds C(b, m), we passed all prior arrangements
            of m bits in the b lower positions, so there must be a 1 bit here.
        */
        if (c <= n)
        {
            /*  Decrement n for the number of prior arrangements.

                Put a 1 bit at this position.  (We shift k later.)

                Update c to C(b-1, m-1) from C(b, m):  C(b-1, m-1) / C(b, m) =
                (b-1)! / (m-1)! / ((b-1)-(m-1))! / (b! / m! / (b-m)!) =
                m / b.

                Decrement m by 1 for this 1 bit.
            */
            n -= c;
            k |= 1;
            c = c * m-- / b;
        }

        /*  Otherwise, merely update c to C(b-1, m) from C(b, m):
            C(b-1, m) / C(b, m) =
            (b-1)! / m! / ((b-1)-m)! / (b! / m! / (b-m)!) = (b-m) / b.
        */
        else
            c = c * (b-m) / b;

        //  Shift k to work on next bit position.
        k <<= 1;
    }
    /*  The loop above can be made sufficient to construct all of k by running
        it down to a final iteration in which b is zero (which requires some
        care in the loop limit and avoiding division by zero in updating c).
        That is mathematically aesthetic, but, once n reaches zero, we can
        handle the final bits directly with the code below.
    */

    /*  The bit at position 0 in the value under construction in k is destined
        to be bit b in the final value, so shift k.
    */
    k <<= b;

    /*  Here n is zero which is the index for all m 1 bits in the low
        positions. Add this to k, and we are done.
    */
    k |= (1u << m) - 1;

    return k;
}


int main(void)
{
    for (unsigned k = 0; k < 32; ++k)
    {
        unsigned m, n;
        BitStringToIndex(k, &m, &n);
        printf("%u %u %u\n", k, m, n);
        unsigned t = IndexToBitString(m, n);
        if (t != k)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, expected (%u, %u) -> %u but got %u.\n",
                m, n, k, t);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

Footnotes
1 This is a well-known elementary combinatorics result. It is sometimes called the “n choose k” function because it is also the number of ways of choosing k objects from n and commonly written nCk. In fact, arranging m 1 bits in b positions is choosing m positions from b positions. However, since the question uses n and k for other purposes, I could not use them for this.
2 The rightmost bits initially contain 1s, so no steps through the list are required to set them to 1, so they do not contribute to the index.

Your IndexToBitString looks like the Buckles algorithm; is that right?

@BobbyOcean these implementations should be faster than your currently accepted answer.

@Nick: Could be. I just wrote it from scratch.

https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/355732.355739

@Nick: Buckles’ and Lybanon’s paper describes things differently, but I think the underlying ideas are essentially the same. The binomial function has a lot of flexibility. E.g., the sum of the function along a diagonal segment equals the difference of the function values by the start and endpoints, and I think that would explain some difference between my expressions and theirs. Note that their code does call the binomial function repeatedly, which mine avoids.

Agreed; your simplification by using the ratios between different values rather than computing them from scratch is definitely a good one.

The trivial solution:
def count_same0(k: int) -> int:
    s = 0
    m = k.bit_count()
    for n in range(k):
        if n.bit_count() == m:
            s += n
    return s

However, you could try to only generate all the numbers < k with a specific bit-count instead and count those.
Here's a simple attempt at doing just that:
def count_same1(k: int) -> int:
    from itertools import permutations
    from math import log2, floor

    m = k.bit_count()
    positions = floor(log2(k)) + 1  # the total number of bit positions 

    s = 0
    # start generating unique permutations of positions #bits
    ps = set()
    for p in permutations([0] * (positions-m) + [1] * m):
        if p not in ps:
            ps.add(p)
            n = 0
            for b in p:
                n = (n << 1) | b
            # stop when we first exceed k
            if n >= k:
                break
            s += n

    return s 

This works, but is very inefficient, since it still has to generate all the permutations that are not unique. And in the end, generating a permutation is a lot slower than just counting the bits.
Instead, it might be better to generate the unique combinations of positions for zeroes for numbers that have a certain number of ones, and then compute those numbers:
def gen_int_n_ones(n: int) -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    from itertools import combinations

    z = 0
    while True:
        bits_cs = list(combinations(range(1, n), z))
        yield from (sum(0 if i in bits else 2**(n-(i+1)) for i in range(n)) for bits in bits_cs)
        z += 1
        n += 1


def count_same2(k: int) -> int:
    s = 0
    for n in gen_int_n_ones(k.bit_count()):
        if n >= k:
            break
        s += n

    return s

However, the naive solution uses operations that are so efficient, it's more efficient to just test all the numbers, instead of working out which to avoid.
Try running this:
def main():
    from timeit import timeit

    for x in range(1, 100):
        print(x, count_same0(x), count_same1(x), count_same2(x))
        print(
            timeit(lambda: count_same0(x), number=10000), 
            timeit(lambda: count_same1(x), number=10000), 
            timeit(lambda: count_same2(x), number=10000)
        )

You'll find that count_same0 is easily the fastest (in fact, just plain fast) and that count_same2 is better than count_same1, but doesn't get close to count_same0.
So I think the simple answer is really:
def n_for_k(k: int) -> int:
    b = k.bit_count()
    return sum(1 for i in range(k) if i.bit_count() == b)

However, for your example value of 123456789123456789123456789, that will take ages to complete. I doubt there's a known simpler solution though, given that (after solving it as described above) I found the sequence on the OEIS as well: https://oeis.org/A079071 and it basically defines the same thing. (and looking at the graph, it doesn't get much better: https://oeis.org/A079071/graph)
Who or what tasked you with solving it for that value?

This appears nearly indentical to the code I provided, and as we both note that this solution does not solve the given K value. The K value was just chosen large. In general, given 100 digit binary numbers I would like to know their index on the list generated, so I chose a K that would reflect that difficulty. I agree the naïve approach is not sufficient. Notice though that if K = 549755811839, then the solution is immediately M = 38 and N = (K - sum(2**i for i in range(38))).bit_count() = 27. This is because N<=M. So fast formulas exist for some K.

I don't disagree, I just wanted to share the result of what I suggested in the comments - I think it's a fruitless direction. However, from looking at the data on OEIS, this looks like the kind of problem that would warrant a math paper if you do solve it. What you're suggesting about 'some K' is merely another way of saying that boundaries can be set on N, which is clear from the graph, and would probably result into a similar kind of formulation for edge cases. But that doesn't guide the way to a general solution for any N, which is what you appear to be asking.

I would suggest asking the broader question on a Mathematics board (as user @barmar suggested), reference the OEIS sequence and see if any mathematicians know of an attack on this problem that has a solution for any N.

You may be correct on that. I incorrectly stated in my edit that I solved "half", it appears to actually be a much smaller percentage, like log(n!) or something like that, and so is probably following some edge or boundary on the graph. Although it does appear that K <-> (M,N) is a 1-1 onto pairing, so in that sense my formula does indeed solve "half" the (M,N) pairs.

floor(log2(k)) + 1 is extremely inefficient. log2 = b.bit_length() would be much better

@phuclv sure, buy obviously it's irrelevant, since it only gets computed once and is completely blown away by the rest of the algorithm.

@phuclv It's also wrong, for example for K= 562949953421311.

@nocomment I just miss a + 1, K.bit_length() + 1 always work correctly because bit_length is always the floor of log2

@phuclv Hmm? No, don't add 1. I was talking about the log way. Always wrong at some point, I don't know why people keep using it, especially experienced people who surely know about the trouble with floats.

@nocomment why not? the result is floored so without adding 1 it's equivalent to floor(log2(k)). The length in bit must be equal to the floor of log2

@phuclv "without adding 1 it's equivalent to floor(log2(k))" - No it's not.

@nocomment the documentation says Equivalently, when abs(x) is small enough to have a correctly rounded logarithm, then k = 1 + int(log(abs(x), 2)). And it's also easily seen from basic math. In fact bit_length is always correct for arbitrarily large values whereas log2 doesn't as it uses limited precision floating-point math. Just prove any positive number where bit_length is wrong and not equivalent to floor(log2(k)). If you don't understand that then stop arguing

@phuclv How do you not see the 1 + that you copied there? You quoted the proof that I'm right.

https://oeis.org/A079071 isn't the same sequence; it only considers the total bit length of each value. So 10 binary is not considered to be the second instance of a single set bit (the first being 1) because it has a 0 in it, which 1 doesn't. However in this question OP is considering all numbers to have the same number of bits as the K value.

Expressing the number as a combination of bits and computing the combination index:
from more_itertools import combination_index
from math import comb

K = 123456789123456789123456789

M = K.bit_length()
c = [i for i, b in enumerate(f'{K:b}') if b == '1']
N = comb(M, len(c)) - 1 - combination_index(c, range(M))

print(N)

Output (same as Dave's):
3594960708495168399327022

Ah darn, I just realized you're after "a simple formula". Oh well. Maybe this is still useful for people who come here looking for simple code.
